# C/Multithreading /Segmentation fault / (May be) Issue with queue for the threads

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, coredump, ucontext

I am trying to create thread library.For this I am trying to implement queue to store the pending threads to be executed.

```
   #include <ucontext.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   typedef struct {
       ucontext_t context;
   }MyThread;

   #define MAX 20
   MyThread queue[MAX];
   int rear=0,front=0;

   void addToQueue(MyThread t)
   {
       if(rear==MAX)
       {
           printf("Queue is full!");
           return;
       }        
       queue[front]=t;
       front+=1;
   }

   MyThread* removeFromQueue()
   {       
       if(front==rear)
       return NULL;        
       rear=rear+1;
       return &(queue[rear-1]);       
   }

   MyThread umain;

   void MyThreadInit (void(*start_funct)(void *), void *args)
   {
    getcontext(&(umain.context));
    char p[64000];
       umain.context.uc_stack.ss_sp =(char *)p;
       umain.context.uc_stack.ss_size = sizeof(p);
       umain.context.uc_link =NULL;
       makecontext(&umain.context,(void(*)(void))start_funct,1,args);
       setcontext(&(umain.context));

   }

    MyThread MyThreadCreate (void(*start_funct)(void *), void *arg)
   {
         MyThread newthread;
       char args[10000];
        getcontext(&(newthread.context));
        newthread.context.uc_stack.ss_sp =(char *)args;
        newthread.context.uc_stack.ss_size = sizeof(args);
        newthread.context.uc_link =NULL;
        makecontext(&newthread.context,(void(*)(void))start_funct,1,arg);
        addToQueue(newthread);

        return newthread;
    }         
    void MyThreadYield(void)
    {
        MyThread* a=removeFromQueue();
        MyThread save;
        if(a != NULL)
        {
         printf("Before yielding the context \n");

         getcontext(&(save.context));
         addToQueue(save);
         //swapcontext(&umain.context,&(a->context));
         setcontext(a);    
         printf("After the swapping the context \n");
        }
        else
        { printf("NULL!!! \n");
        }
    }

    void func1(void *arg)
    {
     printf("func1started \n");        
     MyThreadYield();
    }

    void func2(void *arg)
    {
     printf("func2started \n");
     MyThreadYield();         
    }
    void func12(void *arg)
    {
     printf("func12started \n");
     MyThreadCreate(func1,arg);
     MyThreadCreate(func2,arg);
     MyThreadYield();

    }

    int main(void)
    {
        int i=0;
        printf("inside the main function \n");
        MyThreadInit(func12,&i);

        return 0;
    }

     Output :
     inside the main function
     func12started
     Before yielding the context
     func1started
     Before yielding the context
     func2started
     Before yielding the context
     func1started
     Before yielding the context
     Segmentation fault
```

The reason I mentioned the queue because i tried experimenting by removing below code from 'MyThreadYield' function and it workes fine but doesnt do the intended functionality.
           getcontext(&(save.context));
           addToQueue(save);

Comment: What's your question? What errors do you get? What did you expect? What do you mean by *doesn't do the intended functionality*?

Comment: Your queue can't possibly work. You need to read up on how to write good parallel objects. Even if you fix your memory error, it's going to give you the wrong things.

Comment: Errors I got : (Already mentioned in the output which is at the end of code) segmentation fault.

Comment: My question is that why segmentation fault? Before asking i tried with removing some code related to queue. and it worked perfectly. Hence I think it is around that area.
Intended functionality is mentioned above. To able to store the thread in case of yield funcitonality.

Comment: intended flow is : Main-> umain thread -> umain yield to thread 1 and stored in the queue-> thread 1 yield to thread2 and stored in the queue -> thread2 yield to umain -> umain start executing from last time it left -> print (after swapping the thread) -> successful exit.

Comment: @PatrickCollins , it is possible for you the elaborate more why it wouldnt work? Can you provide relevant web references?

Comment: @AdityaAmbre `queue[front]=t; front+=1;` isn't threadsafe for multiple writers.

Comment: @AdityaAmbre A fantastic book on the topic is "The Art of Multiprocessor Programming" -- I strongly recommend that you check it out.

Comment: @PatrickCollins, it is the experimental code, not the final code.Here I am not considering the semaphore protection, but trying to understand the ucontext routines more.It would be better if someone help me to find the issue in the code.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves , Any inputs for this issue?
May I know why my question received negative votes? I just started posting questions on stackoverflow!

Comment: @AdityaAmbre It was downvoted because the question is nearly unanswerable. However, I decided to post an answer with some of what I think may be the main issues with your queue implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For one, your queue implementation is not thread-safe at this point. Your question strongly suggests that this code will be used in a multi-threaded environment. Having a non thread-safe queue will give you wrong results, and weird things can happen (like `removeFromQueue()` returning the same thing to two different threads, or `addToQueue()` inserting two items in the same position).

Aside from that, your queue implementation would never work. You are not using `front` and `rear` correctly. Look carefully at the insert function:

```
void addToQueue(MyThread t)
{
    if (rear==MAX)
    {
        printf("Queue is full!");
        return;
    }        
    queue[front]=t;
    front+=1;
}
```

You check if `rear` is `MAX`, yet, you write into `queue[front]` and increment `front`. What if I just keep adding items to the queue, eventually reaching the buffer's limit? `rear` will always be 0, `front` will grow indefinitely, and your function will write beyond the limits of `queue`. That's probably the cause of your segmentation fault errors.

I think you wanted to check for `front` instead:

```
void addToQueue(MyThread t)
{
    if (front == MAX)
    {
        printf("Queue is full!");
        return;
    }        
    queue[front]=t;
    front+=1;
}
```

The code for `removeFromQueue()` looks superficially ok, as long as `queue` is a global array (since you're returning a pointer, and can't return pointers to local variables). However, the single, most important fact you have to take out of this answer, is that **your queue implementation will not scale in the long-term**. An array-based queue is a terrible choice. What do you do when you run out of space in the array? What if I insert `MAX` elements, then remove 2 or 3, and try to insert more? Your code will say the queue is full, because it only ever allows you to insert `MAX` elements in total. You could shift every element in the queue to the left when an element is removed, but that's crazy, and extremely inefficient. Or you could increment `front` modulo `MAX`, allowing `rear` to be ahead of `front`, as long as you know that no more than `MAX` elements can be inserted. That would be better, but it would break the logic in `removeFromQueue()`, since the pointers returned earlier will possibly point to a different thread struct as you manipulate the queue - total disaster. Definitely not what you want.

A much, much better approach would be to implement this with a linked list where you keep a pointer to the head and a pointer to the tail. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)#Queue_implementation